# Stumped by DjangoRestFramework

Tags: django, rest

Please help me figure out how to solve the error message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apps.user'`. The complexity of [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sl43oS-36Ms) is several steps above the usual beginners' tutorial and so I had a hard time search for answers. I tested with the standard lines from Django Rest Framework's docs to no avail. I also tested by commenting out everything extraneous to the bare-bottom, basic `users` app (like views.py). The line in the `INSTALLED_APPS` still gives me a long list of erros that end in this--Whether I have `apps.users` or `users.apps.UsersConfig`:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'users'. 
Check that 'apps.users.apps.UsersConfig.name' is correct.
```

This is the first time I have an app inside another folder (ie the `users` folder is inside `apps` folder), I wonder if the folder structure is causing the problem, though this is exactly what the tutorial instructs. I can post more code here if needed, but the github repo is [here](https://github.com/CodeByLine/hackathon_django_API). I've searched through the entire project folder for references to "users", but nothing stood out. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

The folders structure is the following:

```
project_folder
   apps
     users
        apps.py
        models.py
        urls.py
        views.py
        ... 
   config
        settings.py
        urls.py
        ...
   manage.py
```

Comment: what does your settings.py look like ? 
Also, do you have __init__.py in your users folder ?@YCode

Comment: The code you've added at the bottom of `settings.py` is really weird. What is it doing? Also, why are you nesting `users/` inside `apps/`? That's causing the problem. It works if you just add `apps` to `INSTALLED_APPS`, but that's a really weird way to set up an app. You're better off just using `users` as the app directory and getting rid of `apps`. Other apps can sit on the same root level directory later.

Comment: @ashdaily Yes, there is an init.py file there--I created the 'users' app inside the 'users' folder Otherwise, aside from adding the users app (and djangorestfromwork) to the list of INSTALLED_APPS, I didn't do anything else.

Comment: @JohnKealy The last few lines in the settings.py file are for hiding the SECRETS (using dotenv) and using local_settings.py (both of which I just learned).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piqued my interest, so I did a little tinkering with your repo.

It turns out that the `apps/` thing was a bit of a red herring. In end I discovered that the latest version of Django has broken whatever was being done in your tutorial.

**Downgrade to Django 3.1.7.**

This did the trick for me. I've had issues myself with the latest Django update (3.2). You'll also need to fix the typos in your `models.py` (modles, Charfield).

The repo needs a lot of work. To quote the IT crowd, if this repo was a person, I'd shoot it in the face. But I hope that solves the specific problem in your question.

Comment: Thank you so much! In the intervening time, I've concluded the root of all the woes is the 'apps' folder in which the 'users' app resided. So I moved it out of the 'apps' folder (and fixed the typos). Having re-created the users app multiple times, I thought perhaps this tutorial was over my head. Thank you for solving this puzzled!

Comment: PS Not gonna shoot it anytime soon. Ugly it may be, it is mine. And it will get better, one pot mark at a time :-)

Comment: Good on you :) btw I definitely recommend doing it that way, doing away with the apps/ folder. What I do is I create an `api/` sub-folder, and place all my apps, `config/` and `manage.py` there. I just got curious as to why the tutorial worked and yours didn't.